# liquibase initalization is executed in contradiction to the application.properties

Tags: spring-boot, spring-profiles, spring-boot-configuration

Currently I have a SBA (Spring Boot App 1.5.10.RELEASE) which has two configuration property files like `application-default.properties` and `application-oracle.properties`. Furthermore those files are located in `src/main/resources` they end up in the resulting jar file in `BOOT-INF/classes/`
The `applilcation-oracle.properties` contains something like this:

```
#
# Turn off liquibase initialization.
spring.liquibase.enabled=false

# Oracle settings
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe
spring.datasource.username=..
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=...
#
# Hibernate
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=....
#
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.show_sql=false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.use_sql_comments=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

The `application-default.properties` looks similar except for `spring.liquibase.enabled` which is not contained and contains a connection to a local PostgreSQL instead of Oracle.

I have a dependency to liquibase in my pom file.

So now I would like to start my SBA simply via:

```
java -jar x.jar --spring.profiles.active=default ..
```

which prints out as expected that liquibase initialization is running..
afterwards I would like to start it like this:

```
java -jar x.jar --spring.profiles.active=oracle ..
```

and expected that the inialization via liquibase will not happen based on the given `spring.liquibase.enabled=false` but in contradiction to my expectation it will start the initialization via liquibase.

So the question is: Did I oversight something ?

Comment: it depends on what version of spring you are using. looks like it got renamed to "spring.liquibase.enables" in favor of "liquibase.enabled" in 2.0

Comment: Spring Boot Version 1.5.10.RELEASE currently. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: then it's without the "spring" prefix :)

Answer (score 0):

[Default properties for spring boot 1.5.10](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) is:

LIQUIBASE ([LiquibaseProperties](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.5.10.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseProperties.java))

```
liquibase.change-log=classpath:/db/changelog/db.changelog-master.yaml # Change log configuration path.
liquibase.check-change-log-location=true # Check the change log location exists.
liquibase.contexts= # Comma-separated list of runtime contexts to use.
liquibase.default-schema= # Default database schema.
liquibase.drop-first=false # Drop the database schema first.
liquibase.enabled=true # Enable liquibase support.
liquibase.labels= # Comma-separated list of runtime labels to use.
liquibase.parameters.*= # Change log parameters.
liquibase.password= # Login password of the database to migrate.
liquibase.rollback-file= # File to which rollback SQL will be written when an update is performed.
liquibase.url= # JDBC url of the database to migrate. If not set, the primary configured data source is used.
liquibase.user= # Login user of the database to migrate.
```